# Merge datasets using pandas for common variable

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I tried to merge datasets using common variable,
but because the var name is complex just changed inside csv files.

Now I need to merge but still the var name may not be identifiable
KeyError: 'EID'

What shall I do?

data1:

```
Itv Schedule, Data: Itv Session,    EID,    Employer: Organization Name,
Fall 2015, CS,  9b3000a21d0fbc59e648dd7eb61265cb,   Alibaba,
Fall 2015, CS,  3e14213c3e34a38c1e6fa8b9577ecf81,   Amazon,
Fall 2015, CS,  0b87a844f4c607d532b3ee7f4cbae22a,   Credit,
Fall 2015, CS,  9f694bd711a347c2c0177a06505c2462,   Corporation,
Fall 2015, CS,  c41ad017309167498e43592ea15273a4,   Financial,
```

data2:

```
Itv Schedule, Data: Itv Session,    EID,    Employer: Organization Name,
Fall 2016, CS,  94ac45de9cd4847991aab265c750921a,   CS,
Fall 2016, CS,  62b139cfa0b668c7f934f7001a999be6,   IBM,
Fall 2016, CS,  224c539042211ba53add9cc831bc8a33,   Petrol,
Fall 2016, CS,  5f32811c9de563cfe8328847d5d3c180,   Stock,
```

data3:

```
Itv Schedule, Data: Itv Session,    EID,    Employer: Organization Name,
Fall 2017, SAM, 0a1f9785f5c111c373b5034c296c37b3,   Honest,
Fall 2017, SAM, 9f694bd711a347c2c0177a06505c2462,   Corporation,
Fall 2017, CS,  5f32811c9de563cfe8328847d5d3c180,   Stock,
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1516 = pd.read_csv('data1516.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=0, encoding='latin-1')
data1617 = pd.read_csv('data1617.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=0, encoding='latin-1')
data1718 = pd.read_csv('data1718.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=0, encoding='latin-1')


N=[data1516,data1617,data1718]
import functools 
df=functools.reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = "EID", how='outer'), N)

#df = pd.merge(data1516, data1617, on='EID', how='outer')
```

wants to merge instead of doing concat

Comment: These have identical schemas. Concat shoud work, no?

Comment: What is your delimiter/separator?

Comment: @ako The thing is, I want to distinguish years so that I want to use how=outer in merge

Comment: @maxU want to use EID as merge identifier, for delimiter it is , in csv !

Comment: @Nora, could you fix your CSV data sets so that they have `,` as a delimiter?

Comment: sure, p.s. I know that these dataset will be just added by merge due to differences, but I have more dataset which I want to merge

Comment: @Nora, this code is working as expected... What is your question/issue?

Comment: You can distinguish years with `concat` - the variable `Itv Schedule` is present in all three. I don't see the problem.

Comment: will try, thanks @Ako!